# Pine Script Back testing

Tags: scripting, pine-script, binance

I am writing a simple pine script to go Long before 10 mins hourly candle closure and close short after 10 mins after candle closure.

But the script does not apply to previous date / time but only applied from the time I add it to the chart.

I would like to back testing of this simple strategy. Can some one help please?

I am very new to scripting. Appreciate any help.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/ // © jayaguru
//@version=4 
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = minute(timenow)

if (longCondition == 55)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
if (longCondition == 14 or strategy.openprofit < -15 or strategy.openprofit > 40)
    strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [`timenow`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_timenow) variable, which is the current date/time (as in 'now').
Instead, you need to use [`time`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_time) which returns the time of when the bar opens.
Like this:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/ // © jayaguru
//@version=4 
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

longCondition = minute(time)

if (longCondition == 55)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
if (longCondition == 14 or strategy.openprofit < -15 or strategy.openprofit > 40)
    strategy.close_all()
```

See [Access bar times programmatically in TradingView Pine](https://kodify.net/tradingview/date-time/bar-time/#access-bar-times-programmatically-in-tradingview-pine) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much Bjorn. appreciate your help. Could you please help if the below statement is wrong. it does not work. i am trying to be in the position until either it hits the netloss or profit but does not seem to be working.   

if (longCondition == 14 or strategy.netprofit < -100 or strategy.netprofit > 60)
    strategy.close_all()